# Change src with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image, mousehover

I'm triyng to change the src of an image when i hover it ,but change it back when i no longer hover it.My problem is even if i ask just for the image with the src="img/fb-logo.png" it changes all the images when i hover over them and didnt change them back when i no longer hover.
My code looks like this :
HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div id="social-img">
        <a href=""><img src="img/fb-logo.png" alt="Sartoria Dana Design Facebook Page" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/instagram-logo.png" alt="Sartoria Dana Design Instagram Page" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/twitter-logo.png" alt="Sartoria Dana Design Twitter Page" /></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/gplus-logo.png" alt="Sartoria Dana Design Google Plus Page" /></a>                            <a href=""><img src="img/yt-logo.png" alt="Sartoria Dana Design Youtube Channel" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Jquery:

```
$('footer #social img').mouseover(function () {
    if (this.src = "img/fb-logo.png") {
        this.src = "img/fb-logo-change.png";
    }
});
```

Comment: Why should it change it back? You don't have any code that would change it back.

Comment: I was thinking that the mouse over acts just when i hover it then changes back the effect , my bad .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it with a simple dataset. You must define all data what you need, in this case we can use `data-hover` and `data-out` and then manage it with jquery. Try this (run code snippet to see it working):

```js
    $('img').on('mouseover',function () {
        var data = $(this).attr('data-hover');
        $(this).attr("src", data); // data-hover
    })
    $('img').on('mouseout', function() {
        var data = $(this).attr('data-out');
        $(this).attr("src", data); // data-out
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/ffffff&text=Image+1" 
       data-hover="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/ffffff/000000&text=Image+2"
       data-out="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/ffffff&text=Image+1" />
```

Comment: I triyed and it doesn't do anything when i hover.

Comment: Just one question. Wouldn't that work if i use .mouseover ?

Comment: Yes, but delegating functions are better and save your life many times. Search about it. Please, upvote my answer ;)